# Access individual JSON array item and use for blog post dynamically

Tags: arrays, axios, nuxt.js

I'm building a simple Nuxt JS blog with a `blog.json` file containing an array of blog posts which contains:

- Title (String)
- Body (HTML markup)
- Creation (Date)

I will attach the format of this shortly. I know how to iterate over each array item and display it on the page, and I also have a basic understanding and some basic experience with [dynamic routing in Nuxt JS](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes).

The problem I'm currently facing is I need to be able to access individual array items and use them as blog posts, e.g: `pages/blog/_slug` where `_slug` would be the title of a blog post, with hyphens + all lowercase automatically.

I'm wondering how I would access for instance the **Winter blog post** in my example and be able to go to `mysite.com/blog/winter-blog-post` using the following JSON format:

```
{
  "blogs": [
    {
      "title": "Summer blog post",
      "body": "<div class=\"post\">My blog content</div>",
      "created": "2019-03-14 10:08:00"
    }
    {
      "title": "Winter blog post",
      "body": "<div class=\"post\">My blog content</div>",
      "created": "2019-03-15 10:08:00"
    },
    {
      "title": "Spring blog post",
      "body": "<div class=\"post\">My blog content</div>",
      "created": "2019-03-16 10:08:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I essentially want to be able to go to `mysite.com/blog/winter-blog-post` and have it use the content from that particular array item.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have your pages set up correctly and you can reach `/blog/_slug`, so it really is just a matter of passing the required params and converting them as needed. In blog.vue you would have a list of your posts and a click on something would navigate to the full article. That click event would trigger a method where you can manipulate the title and use it as a param. So if you have a 'Read More...' button you would assign `@click="readMore(blog.title)"` to that button.

Then in your methods you take the passed 'title' parameter, change it as you want, and trigger the route change.

```
methods: {
  readeMore(title) {
    let passedTitle = title.toLowerCase()
    passedTitle = passedTitle.replace(" ", "-")
    this.$router.push('/blog/' + passedTitle)
  }
}
```

Then in your _slug.vue you take the passed param, change it back and use that to find your article.

```
export default {
     asyncData({params, $axios }) {
      let title = params.passedTitle.replace("-", " ")
      let oldTitle = title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title.slice(1)
        // make your query however you do, if with axios...
        $axios.get('/posts', {
          params: {
            title: oldTitle
          }
        })
    //or if its a vuex state item...
    //let post = this.$store.state.posts.find((p) => p.title === oldTitle)
      return post
    },
}
```

Comment: `passedTitle.replace(" ", "-")` only seems to replace the first whitespace between the first two words of a title, e.g: "My Title Is Here" - only a hyphen would appear between the first two words?

Comment: Yes, right you are. You could do this instead: `passedTitle.split(" ").join("-")`.